# FTP over SSL/TLS on WEC2013

Tags: ssl, ftp, windows-embedded-compact

does anybody know if it is possible (and if yes how) to activate ftp over SSL/TLS on WEC2013?
FTPD is activated in the Image and we also got httpd with ssl working. I imagine that if https is working that also ftps should work but I cannot find any documentation about this or a hint which registry keys we have to configure.

Thanks and regards

Dominik

Answer (score 0):

I have configured for Windows system. In those days I had follow below link

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9769/69/ssl-for-ftp-on-windows-servers

Comment: Hi Mohit, thanks for your answer. The problem I have is that I do not have a GUI in the Windows embedded. So I'm reliant to the registry. I tried modifieing/creating a ftp-site in a normal IIS (Windows 10/Server) but I did not find any registryentries regarding this settings. 
Regards Dominik